# How to extract specific data from Ajax request in laravel in controller

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.4, i have made an AJAX request from the views then routed it through routes then i am getting the data on controller but in this format:

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-
US;q=0.6,la;q=0.4,de;q=0.2 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 212 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ild3MlNjSkNyYTl1TmxqWGE2bldIXC9RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImZYNFpIcWZyOURCVm9wdG11aWFwa2ZcLzJNdFdmZm9DRjVEZ1pqQ1AzbzhTRWpQTTh2NmZZc2pZTjB2TFUyZ3BDU2hHbXlCZXdoOEgzRHZsdXBLWTUyZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMDZkNGExOTBhZTgzNGNmMzNlZTEyMzExMWEwOTk3NzEwYWNiOTc5MGJlYzc2YzVhODJjNzMyMGVkN2M2NjE5NiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkVpaW1vZ0NKbjVnYWJDK0N2Ukh1OEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia3Jkd1dHWjRhcml3Slp3UjZUa25VZ1RKdmt3cVl2T01LSmdVS0dsbW5Dc1IwcTB4bFRZdFA0RjBPdlBCaVFPaEtYaU1uYXB2Sm5yNmhNN3g5MW9TS3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQ2ZDhiM2ExYmEyMDE0MDg3NGM1NjM5NDMxNDdjYWExODgyYzc4NmE3YjIyYjUzNTdhOWJmNDk3ZmRmZTI4YjYifQ%3D%3D Host: www.hms.com Origin: http://www.hms.com Referer: http://www.hms.com/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36 X-Csrf-Token: CqeOgqQt05Oplb1HTnlCygkDzV0fFFiqWvBZ2r2j X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest data%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=_token&data%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=CqeOgqQt05Oplb1HTnlCygkDzV0fFFiqWvBZ2r2j&data%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=username&data%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=admin&data%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=password&data%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=admin
```

i want to extract `username & password` only how should i achieve it?

This is my route code:

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

This is my controller code wher i am getting ajax request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
 {
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }

    public function login(Request $request)
        {
            return $request;
        }
}
```

This is my ajax code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function()
            {
                // var form = new FormData($('.login-form')[0]);

                var data = [];
                var splittedFormData = $(".login-form").serialize().split('&');

                $.each(splittedFormData, function (key, value)
                    {
                        item = {};
                        var splittedValue = value.split('=');               
                        item["name"] = splittedValue[0];
                        item["value"] = splittedValue[1];
                        data.push(item);
                    });

                $.ajax({
                            url: '/login',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            data: {data},
                        })
                .done(function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                })
                .fail(function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                })
                .always(function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                });
            });
    });
```

How to extract the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are making this more complicated for yourself by not using standard behavior for a post? You could send in

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $(".login-form").serialize(),
 })
```

And on the server side you could use

```
$email = $request->get('email');
$password = $request->get('password');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function login(Request $request)
        {
            return $request->all();
        }
```

Comment: i already tried it, it shows the same thing i posted like ajax but i wanted to extract the data like if there are 4 variables via a post i wanted to extract only specific data

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, You need to loop and get 'username' and 'password' data like:

```
$userName = '';
$password = '';
foreach($request->data as $reqKey => $reqData){
    //For username
    if($reqData[$reqKey]['name'] == 'username'){
        $userName = $reqData[$reqKey]['value'];
    }

    //For password
    if($reqData[$reqKey]['name'] == 'password'){
        $password = $reqData[$reqKey]['value'];
    }
}
```

Now you can use `$userName` and `$password` for next operation...

Comment: this will increase the load of executing the code more and also is too long

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public function login(Request $request){
  $re =['username'=>'', 'password'=>''];
  if($request->has(['username', 'password'])){
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;

    //Here you can use $username and $password

    $re =['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password];
  }
  return response()->json($re);
}
```

See this tutorial about Laravel Request and retrieving input data:

http://coursesweb.net/laravel/requests#anc_rin

Comment: The very 1st answer is accurate with less code please have a look at it

Comment: Laravel Request class does not have 'get' method. It inherits it form Symfony Request class.